# Reading integer values in a file which contains brackets

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read integer values in a file which contains strings like this one :

```
1 (23 4 5)
```

Here's my Java code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EssaiLecture {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        try {

            File file = new File("try.txt");


                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("");

           while(sc.hasNext()){

               try{

                  System.out.println(sc.nextInt());

               }
               catch (InputMismatchException in) {

                  sc.next();

               }

           }  

              sc.close();
            }
              catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

}
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Here is the problem : I can't read integer value composed of 2 (or more) characters.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Just a friendly advice, get rid of the french words (such as EssaiLecture). Thanks

Comment: Try this:      Pattern myPattern = new Pattern.compile("[^0-9]");
         
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(myPattern);

Answer (score 2):

As already seen from the output using an empty `String` as the delimiter causes the input to be split into individual characters — You could use a non-digit pattern expression

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\D+");
```

where

- `\\D` - matches a non-digit
- `+` - greedy quantifier to match all available non-digit characters

Comment: Can you explain to me the difference between my regex and yours ("[^0-9]" and "\\D+") ?

Comment: The only real difference is the `+` greedy qualifier - without it not all non-digit characters are matched, resulting in `Scanner` not finding any integers

Comment: Wow, thanks I didn't know such things as greedy qualifiers existed. I love SO.

Answer (score 0):

Are the numbers always separated by a space and can you add a space between the brackets and the numbers? If so change your delimiter to " " and that should do it whilst also avoiding the use of regular expressions.

Comment: Changing delimiter to a space (" ") will not work as the scanner will tokenize the input as 1, (23, 4, 5) and will output 1 4.
If the input can be changed to have a space after every character, like: 1 ( 23 4 5 ) ,then changing the delimiter would do the trick.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for taking the time to clarify, I had a feeling after posting that it would probably work like that. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use a regular expression to split between non-digits.

```
package controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class EssaiLecture {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        try {

            File file = new File("try.txt");

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("[^0-9]");

            while(sc.hasNext()){

                try{
                    String string = sc.next();
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    System.out.println(a);

                }
                catch (InputMismatchException in) {
                    sc.next();
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e){

                }

            }

            sc.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```